# Why would lamp A be shorted here in this circuit when testing the circuit with a power supply?

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics, short-circuits

I'll really appreciate a response to this question, thanks for considering.

Suppose I have this circuit (image from a CIE past paper question):

[image: circuit]

Actual text (image here) in the problem:

[image]

It is said that it would be advisable to test the circuit using an ohm-meter with negligible current rather than with a power supply (the ohm-meter would be connected across the terminals x and y), because using a power supply instead would cause shorted lamp A to cause damage to the lamps or supply. To provide some context: lamp C is shorted according to all the data the question provides, the circuit is being used to detect the faulty lamp (lamp C was found to be shorted after answering following questions).

I require clarification on this and I'll appreciate it. I don't know where to start explaining this because I don't understand how exactly "shorted lamp A would cause damage to the supply/lamps" to quote the solution to  this question, where I don't understand how/when lamp A even gets shorted. I really need clarification on the concept, thanks. I did try to research about this but found nothing useful.

[image: verbaitm]

Comment: What is the actual text of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the problem in full, but I assume the answer to your question is that *if* you close the circuit and *if* A is shorted, then you have no resistance (or a very little resistance), as $S_1$ is shorted and $A$ is also shorted, which would cause *very* high currents if connected to a high voltage source. Potentially dangerous.

I assume you know the following, but let's be clear. Assume the path from $y$ to $x$ passing through $S_1$ and $A$ has a total resistance of $r_0$, then if you connect it to a power source with voltage $V$ of course you get a current $I=V/r_0$. Now, if $A$ is shorted then $r_0\approx 0$ and so $I$ can be very high.

Basically, the question is equivalent to "why should you never in general connect a potentially shorted circuit to a power source?" and the answer is "because it can lead to very high currents".

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for,  so  (please view the image for the answer text in my post) means that A won't necessarily be shorted, but that if it *was* to be shorted it could cause very high currents? Please confirm, thanks.

Comment: Yes. If you have the doubt that A is shorted, then you should not even try with high power. If you know that A is fine while C or B are shorted, you could (still: shouldn't) use a power source as any voltage load will be adsorbed by A, provided it has enough resistance. But testing in general should always be done with a ohm-meter if you are afraid there might be faulty components!